# Regex treating accentuated letters as word boundary

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:

```
^\s*((\b[^0-9]+\b)\s*){2}$
```

This regex expects the string to have two words with no number. Thus, for instance, `/^\s*((\b[^0-9]+\b)\s*){2}$/g.test('Word Otherword')` returns `true`, as expected, and `/^\s*((\b[^0-9]+\b)\s*){2}$/g.test('OnlyOneWord')` returns `false`, as it contains only one word.

The problem is that Regex is treating accentuated characters like `ã` or `é` as words boundaries (`\b`). This way, if I test `/^\s*((\b[^0-9]+\b)\s*){2}$/g.test('João')` it returns `true', as it were two words instead of only one.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: BTW, if you plan to match a string consisting of two chunks of non-digit chars, just use `/^[^0-9]+\s+[^0-9]+$/`. Note `[^0-9]` matches spaces, too.

Comment: It seems to be, but simply replacing `\b` with `(?:^|\\s)` doesn't work at all. With `/^\s*(((?:^|\\s)[^0-9]+(?:^|\\s))\s*){2}$/g.test("João Ferreira")` we have `false` instead of `true`.

Comment: Do not try to fix your regex, it is a mess. You need to completely redesign it according to some rules (you have not provided any pattern requirements in the question).

Comment: Well, I don't want to match only two characters. I want to match *at least* two. This one in my question is just a reproducible example. But in practice I would run `^\s*((\b[^0-9]+\b)\s*){2,}$`, so it matches 2 or more.

Comment: To match 2 or more whitespace-separated non-digit chunks you may use `/^\s*[^0-9\s]+(?:\s+[^\s0-9]+)+\s*$/`

Comment: Well, it seems to work. So, can I say {x,y} is useless?

Comment: No, `{x,y}` is very useful. However, you should not try to shorten the pattern to sacrifice precision of matching.

Comment: Well given that this was marked as duplicate I'll give you the regex here `/^\D*[A-zÀ-ÿ ]\D+\s\D+/g` I've had good luck with that. Happy Coding